# PWM frequency and control system sampling frequency in dc-dc converters

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, power-electronics, control-system, control-theory

I am trying to control the output voltage of a simple dc-dc buck converter, which is *digitally controlled*. The output voltage is sampled, and the control algorithm is run, at every \$T_s\$ seconds, while the PWM frequency is \$ f_{sw} = \frac{1}{T_{sw}} \$, with \$ T_{sw}= 0.1\times T_{s}\$. In other words, the sampling frequency and the frequency at which the controller is run, is much lower than the PWM frequency. I.e. the controller is "undersampled" (please correct me if this expression is inappropriate here).

What does this difference in control sampling frequency and PWM switching frequency imply in terms of controller design? In the literature, the controller sampling/running frequency is most of the times chosen the same as the PWM switching frequency, and I could not find a source explaining what happens when the controller runs slower than the PWM.

Thank you

Comment: What happens? The response time is slower. In some  cases the control loop frequency is around 1kHz as the load cannot change as quickly as the switching freq.

Comment: The switching frequency and the bandwidth of the output LC and control loop are fairly independent so it's not clear from your question what you are seeing as a problem here. *In the literature, the controller sampling/running frequency is most of the times chosen the same as the PWM switching frequency* - not literature I'm aware of.

Comment: Why is `Tsw` selected as `10 x Ts` for your system if literature says they are usually chosen to be the same ?

Comment: @AJN, because the controller cannot sample and run as fast as the PWM

Comment: Did you mean `Tsw = Ts/10`? The other equation means that pwm is running slower than control update frequency. ???

Comment: Hi @AJN, you are right, I have edited the question